# Prevent button background image from stretching

Tags: android

I'm using an image as the background for a button. The problem is when i turn the device horizontally, the button adjusts to landscape and the image gets stretched. 
Is there a way to prevent the image from stretching or am i going to need different image sizes for portrait and landscape?

Comment: are you using as a background. try using as android:src="yourimage"

Answer (score 1):

Use [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) image to avoide image from stretching

Comment: And try this Nine-Patch Editor, I think it's much better then the one provided in the SDK. http://weblookandfeel.com/nine-patch-editor/